# Adding textbox value with button in C#

Tags: c#

How to add text to a `TextBox` with `Button`? I know how to do it but if there are many textboxes I can't .if anyone know please help me .

```
Private void button1_Click(object sender, Even target e)
{
    Textbox1.text=Textbox1.text+"a";
}
```

This is only for one textbox and for others textboxes I also want to use this button to add text to textbox.

Comment: [so] is not a _free coding_ website. Please show us the effort you've put in and what you've tried so far. We're here to help when you run in to problems but **not** to write your code for you. Since it's your first question here i'd recommend you take the [tour] and read the [ask] page to learn how to ask a proper question.

Comment: please add wot u have tried

Comment: @SruthiSuresh: Please use proper english even for commenting, sometimes our short forms may confuse others, sometime they thought that its a  typo as well

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
        Private void button1_Click(object sender, Even target e)
        {
            Textbox1.text = Textbox1.text + "a";
            Textbox2.text = Textbox2.text + "a";
            Textbox3.text = Textbox3.text + "a";

        }
```

Comment: but when you click the button the pointer or cursor will move its focus from textbox to button.